# Definition of "burris"

Tags: definiciones, modismos, méxico

What is the meaning of `burris`?

RAE and Google are no help.  It seems to be a very slang term, and from context it relates to humor or sarcasm.  It may be a Mexican term.

Comment: Could it be an altered form of "burro"?

Comment: Could you please post the context in which you saw the word? It's not an spanish word, as you say, might be slang and we need context.

Comment: @sanchy: I would love to, but I've heard the word a few times in various contexts, and don't have any of them handy to quote, so I would only base it off of my imperfect memory.

Comment: @Flimzy I'd say Alfredo's answer is probably correct. Hope you found the help you needed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's like a colloquial diminutive form of **burro** used in Mexico. It is used primarily to doesn't sound too harsh and is mainly used by women. Examples:

> menso -> mensis
>
> tonto -> tontis
>
> burro -> burris

Comment: So it's a less-rude/playful way of calling someone an "ass"?

Comment: @Filmzy yes, that's it.

Comment: @Flimzy I think "burris" is more a "dummy" than an "ass"

Comment: @Newbie: So a playful "dumbass" :)

Comment: @Flimzy hahaha exactly! :)

Comment: It's used in Peru too.