# Terminación "-atis" en lugar de "-aste" en México

Tags: méxico, coloquialismos, sufijos

La banda sonora original del juego GTA V incluye un tema interpretado por "Don Cheto" en la que el estribillo dice:

> ¿Por qué te **tatuatis**?, ¿Por qué te **pintatis**?

refiriéndose a

> ¿Por qué te **tatuaste**? ¿Por qué te **pintaste**?

¿Tiene este uso de la terminación -atis en lugar de -aste algún significado particular en México?

Podéis ver y escuchar la canción en este [enlace a YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfXid_DUI-A).

Comment: ¿Nos puedes dar un enlace para escuchar el contexto?

Comment: Se me ocurre que puede ser la forma *pintastes* o *tatuastes* –común en el español medieval y clásico y aun hoy algunas regiones hispanohablantes–, donde la primera *s* pueda haber sido aspirada y la *e* se haya convertido en una *i*. ([Ver sección 4.4f](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=huUBXXXWOqdiikWk)). A ver si hay algún mejicano que puedo aclararlo.

Comment: Yo también pensé algo así, pero **sospecho** que tiene que ver con un lenguaje de zona rural, aunque sólo es una sospecha

Comment: Algunas personas poco educadas y en algunas regiones rurales de Colombia dirían **tatuates** y **pintates** usando la terminación "-ates" en lugar de "-atis".

Comment: Creo que es otro caso de [este fenómeno](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3831/12).

Comment: @Yay mexicano se escribe con **x**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Don Cheto" utiliza el estereotipo de una persona mexicana que viene de algún rancho (alguna zona rural alejada de la ciudad, también considerado pueblo). En México se da el caso particular de que la gente de los ranchos (o pueblos) tiende a cambiar la terminación de las palabras como lo muestra la canción mencionada. El cantante en cuestión intenta hacer una parodia de la gente pueblerina de México y aunque no todos tienen esa forma de hablar, es un estereotipo muy asentado. Otros ejemplos serían:

> fuiste = juiste
>
> viniste = vinites

Cabe mencionar que este tipo de parodias e imitaciones tienen una intención de burla. Generalmente las zonas rurales (pueblos, ranchos), antaño utilizaban (algunos aún utilizan) lenguas indigenas, y por ende su español tiene algunas palabras e inclusive un acento muy distintivo.

Comment: ¡Gracias por el último párrafo! Qué bueno que aclararse que esto tienen una intención de mofarse de las personas indígenas por su español.

Answer (score 2):

Este tipo de alteraciones del lenguaje es más común en México de lo que la mayoría de los mismos Mexicanos nos damos cuenta. En realidad no tiene ningún significado especial.

A pesar de que es de la opinión generalizada que este tipo de modificaciones es exclusiva de los grupos indígenas; tal percepción es errónea. Si bién pudo ser ocasionada por la pronunciación de los indígenas al estar aprendiendo el español, también es cierto que grandes regiones adoptaron costumbres ligüísticas semejantes. Existen muchas variaciones de estos sufijos en México:

- **Tatuaste =>** tatuates, tatuatis, tatuastes, tatuatesn.
- **Pintaste =>** pintates, pintatis, pintastes, pintatesn.

En general, las palabras con la terminación **-ste** tendrán estas alteraciones. p. ej. fuiste, viniste, trajiste, regalaste.

Su uso no está limitado al uso de los indígenas o rancheros y son usados también en las zonas urbanas

---

La otra alteración que mencionas que consiste en sustituir el sonido de la **f** o **h** por **j** es mucho menos común en personas con un estudio formal mínimo  de 6 a 9 años (primaria y secundaria). Y tampoco tienen un significado especial.

**fuerza** =>  juerza.
**Felipe** => Gelipe o Jelipe.
**hijo** => jijo.
**hoyo** => joyo

Otras alteraciones  son **h** o **b** por **g** pero estas son mucho más comunes y casi estoy seguro que no son exclusivas de México.

**huevo** => güevo.
**huarache** => guarache.
**huerto** => güerto.
**bueno** => güeno.

Y no olvidemos el típico **we** (se pronuncia güe) mexicano que es de mal gusto a menos que haya una familiaridad muy cercana; de lo contrario, puede tomarse como un insulto.

¿Cómo estás **we**?

**buey** => güey => güe => we
.